# How to shorten urls in codeigniter using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to know if there is any way to shorten urls in a codeigniter using .htaccess. Like for example I have example.com/user/account/settings, I would like to shorten the url to example.com/settings. In the same way we remove index.php from the address bar, is there a way to remove more items from the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done by `routes.php` file in your CodeIgniter application folder. [Documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

For your example it would be really easy, just add a line to the file:

```
$route['settings'] = 'user/account/settings';
```

Comment: But routing adds a route and redirects it to the specified url. I don't want the routing to be done, instead want to only shorten urls. Means that both the urls when typed in the address bar will load the same content

Comment: Routes loads the controller, shortening the URL, it does not redirect.

Comment: But my controller would be user, function would be account and settings would be the varible passed. So if I add a route similar to above wouldn't it try to load the settings controller which doesn't exist?

Comment: No, CodeIgniter looks at routes first, for example, if there would be a controller `settings` it would not be loaded, and could be loaded if you would add another route to it, like `$route['my_settings'] = 'settings';`, then you can access `settings` controller by `example.com/my_settings`

Comment: Thanks Vlakarados. It works for me. Was a fool to waste time in searching over the web when I already knew the answer.. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs: e.g

```
example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
```

You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.